Download file through OneDriver Picker JavaScript
I cloned the MS OneDriver FilePicker Repo (https://github.com/OneDrive/samples/tree/master/samples/file-picking).
I'm currently trying around in the "javascript-basic-consumer" sample. I modified some of the code by hand and some through AI. Azure is configured according to the readme and according to the MS learning article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online).
Upload is working, but I can't get the download to work. Neither with documention nor with the help of the other samples or AI.
Could somebody help me out so I get a download after I selected the file and pressed on the "select"-button?
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.19.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
    <script>
        const baseUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/picker";
        const params = {
            sdk: "8.0",
            entry: {
                oneDrive: {
                    files: {},   
                }
            },
            authentication: {},
            messaging: {
                origin: "http://localhost:3000",
                channelId: "27"
            },
            typesAndSources: {
                mode: "files",
                pivots: {
                    oneDrive: true,
                    recent: true,
                },
            },
            selection:{
                mode: "multiple",
            },
        };

        
        let port = null;

        async function launchPicker() {
            const frame = document.getElementById("iframe-id");
            const doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;

            const authToken = await getToken();

            const queryString = new URLSearchParams({
                filePicker: JSON.stringify(params),
            });

            const url = `${baseUrl}?${queryString}`;

            const form = doc.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("action", url);
            form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
            doc.body.append(form);

            const input = doc.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", "access_token");
            input.setAttribute("value", authToken);
            form.appendChild(input);

            form.submit();

            window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "https://onedrive.live.com") {
                    return;
                }

                const message = event.data;

                if (message.type === "initialize" && message.channelId === params.messaging.channelId) {
                    port = event.ports[0];
                    port.addEventListener("message", messageListener);
                    port.start();
                    port.postMessage({ type: "activate", });
                }
            });
        }

        async function messageListener(message) {
            
            switch (message.data.type) {
                case "notification":
                    console.log(`notification: ${message.data}`);
                    break;
                case "command":
                    port.postMessage({
                        type: "acknowledge",
                        id: message.data.id,
                    });

                    const command = message.data.data;

                    switch (command.command) {
                        case "authenticate":
                            const token = await getToken();
                            if (typeof token !== "undefined" && token !== null) {
                                port.postMessage({
                                    type: "result",
                                    id: message.data.id,
                                    data: {
                                        result: "token",
                                        token,
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                console.error(`Could not get auth token for command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "close":
                            win.close();
                            break;
                        case "pick":
                            console.log(`Picked: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);
                            document.getElementById("pickedFiles").innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(command, null, 2)}</pre>`;
                            port.postMessage({
                                type: "result",
                                id: message.data.id,
                                data: {
                                    result: "success",
                                },
                            });
                            win.close();
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.warn(`Unsupported command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`, 2);
                            port.postMessage({
                                result: "error",
                                error: {
                                    code: "unsupportedCommand",
                                    message: command.command
                                },
                                isExpected: true,
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh; flex-direction: column;">
    <iframe id="iframe-id" width="1080" height="680" style="border: none;"></iframe>
    <br />
    <div id="pickedFiles"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        launchPicker(); // This will automatically launch the picker when the page is fully loaded
    };
</script>

</html>

That's my code so far. I read in order to download you need to import the Graph API but I didn't get that to work.
Most likely there's some code needed in the case "pick". Additionally probably in "params" as well as far as I understood in the documentation.
After I put some download code in "params" acoording to the documentation I either get a blank site oder it loads after picking a file and then nothing happens again. That's one edit I made in "params":
 commands?: {
    /**
     * Specifies the behavior for file-picking.
     */
    pick?: {
      /**
       * A special action to perform when picking the file, before handing the result
       * back to the host app.
       */
      action?: "select" | "share" | "download" | "move";
      /**
       * A custom label to apply to the button which picks files.
       * This must be localized by the host app if supplied.
       */
}
}

Copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/v8-schema?view=odsp-graph-online&source=recommendations
THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANY HELP!


Most likely there's some code needed in the case "pick". Additionally probably in "params" as well as far as I understood in the documentation.

Yes, to enable the download functionality after selecting a file and pressing the "select" button in the OneDrive file picker, you need to handle the pick action and initiate the download process.

Update the params object to include the commands section with the pick action set to "download".

Modify the messageListener function to handle the pick action and initiate the download process when a file is picked.


<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.19.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
    <script>
        const baseUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/picker";
        const params = {
            sdk: "8.0",
            entry: {
                oneDrive: {
                    files: {},   
                }
            },
            authentication: {},
            messaging: {
                origin: "http://localhost:3000",
                channelId: "27"
            },
            typesAndSources: {
                mode: "files",
                pivots: {
                    oneDrive: true,
                    recent: true,
                },
            },
            selection:{
                mode: "multiple",
            },
            commands: {
                pick: {
                    action: "download"
                }
            }
        };

        
        let port = null;

        async function launchPicker() {
            const frame = document.getElementById("iframe-id");
            const doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;

            const authToken = await getToken();

            const queryString = new URLSearchParams({
                filePicker: JSON.stringify(params),
            });

            const url = `${baseUrl}?${queryString}`;

            const form = doc.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("action", url);
            form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
            doc.body.append(form);

            const input = doc.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", "access_token");
            input.setAttribute("value", authToken);
            form.appendChild(input);

            form.submit();

            window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "https://onedrive.live.com") {
                    return;
                }

                const message = event.data;

                if (message.type === "initialize" && message.channelId === params.messaging.channelId) {
                    port = event.ports[0];
                    port.addEventListener("message", messageListener);
                    port.start();
                    port.postMessage({ type: "activate", });
                }
            });
        }

        async function messageListener(message) {
            switch (message.data.type) {
                case "notification":
                    console.log(`notification: ${message.data}`);
                    break;
                case "command":
                    port.postMessage({
                        type: "acknowledge",
                        id: message.data.id,
                    });

                    const command = message.data.data;

                    switch (command.command) {
                        case "authenticate":
                            const token = await getToken();
                            if (typeof token !== "undefined" && token !== null) {
                                port.postMessage({
                                    type: "result",
                                    id: message.data.id,
                                    data: {
                                        result: "token",
                                        token,
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                console.error(`Could not get auth token for command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "close":
                            win.close();
                            break;
                        case "pick":
                            console.log(`Picked: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`);
                            // If you want to handle the file data, you can do so here
                            const fileData = command.data;
                            
                            // Initiate the download process
                            const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                            downloadLink.href = fileData.webUrl;
                            downloadLink.download = fileData.name;
                            downloadLink.click();
                            
                            // Close the picker
                            win.close();
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.warn(`Unsupported command: ${JSON.stringify(command)}`, 2);
                            port.postMessage({
                                result: "error",
                                error: {
                                    code: "unsupportedCommand",
                                    message: command.command
                                },
                                isExpected: true,
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh; flex-direction: column;">
    <iframe id="iframe-id" width="1080" height="680" style="border: none;"></iframe>
    <br />
    <div id="pickedFiles"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        launchPicker(); // This will automatically launch the picker when the page is fully loaded
    };
</script>

</html>


In the messageListener function, when the pick action is received, the URL of the selected file (fileData.webUrl) is obtained, and then a temporary anchor element (downloadLink) is created to initiate the download process. Finally, the picker window is closed.



Hey, thanks for your in depth reply!
Unfortunatly it's not working for me.


I understand most of the changes, since I've played around with a few of them. What I don't get is, why you close the picker? I've modified the code, so it opens the picker in an iFrame and not in a popup.
However even if its on purpose, it doesnt download anything + it doesnt close the picker.


The last screenshot you provided me: Is this one from the "typescript react"-sample? Because I dont have that in my "javascript basic consumer"-sample. Those buttons are only present in the react one.




Since I dont have a download-button, it only lets me select items. After I select a file it loads a while but then nothing happens.

-> Could you perhaps help me out once again please?
Edit because I accidentally pressed enter.

-> Since I can't post screens, a link: https://ibb.co/9nmQTdn
